# Scheme Tree Depth

Tags: tree, scheme, racket

I'm trying to write a function that takes a node and returns the depth of the tree rooted at this node. I have the following code so far:

```
(define (make-tree value left right)
  (list value left right))

(define (value T) (car T))
(define (right T) (caddr T))
(define (left T) (cadr T))

(define (insert x T)
  (cond ((null? T) (make-tree x '() '()))
        ((eq? x (value T)) T)
        ((< x (value T)) (make-tree (value T)
                                    (insert x (left T))
                                    (right T)))
        ((> x (value T)) (make-tree (value T)
                                    (left T)
                                    (insert x (right T))))))
```

I'm not exactly sure where to proceed from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The depth of a tree is defined as:

1. an empty tree has depth 0
2. a non empty tree has depth 1 + the maximum of the depth of the children

In code it would look like this:

```
(define (tree-depth tree)
  (if (tree-empty? tree) 
      0
      (+ 1 (max (tree-depth (tree-left tree))
                (tree-depth (tree-right tree))))))
```